# Dealing with data from the same user twice when moving through a loop in R

Tags: r, csv

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~person_id, ~timestamp,
  "1", "02:26:10.000000",
  "1", "03:45:37.000000",
  "2", "22:03:39.000000",
  "3", "11:46:24.000000",
  "4", "18:26:55.000000",
  "5", "17:01:20.000000",
  "5", "03:10:17.000000",
  "6", "23:16:05.000000",
)
df
```

Now let's say I import individual .csv files that each match the person_id like so:

```
  user_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", path = here("data"),
                           full.names = TRUE)
  
  user_files <- user_files[sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(user_files)) %in% df$person_id]
```

There will naturally be fewer .csv files than the length of df$person_id because persons "1" and "5 appear twice in df$person_id

I would now like to run a for loop that runs a program on each csv file. HOWEVER, where there are more than one of the same person_id, I would like to re-run the loop using the same csv file (since it's the same person again but a different timestamp so will yield different results).

This is what the loops look like

```
 for(i in seq(1:length(user_files))) {

    user_file <- read_csv(user_files[i])

#Run lots of analysis on the CSV file

}
```

Now I need something in the loop that says "if df$person_id occurs more than once, repeat the loop using the same CSV file". Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `user_files` are `unique`, then match the `user_files` with the 'df$person_id' use that index to subset the 'user_files'

```
v1 <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(user_files))
user_files2 <- na.omit(user_files[match(df$person_id, v1)])
```

Now, loop over 'user_files2'

---

Or a better approach is to `merge/join` with the original dataset and loop over the filtered data `user_files` column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- inner_join(df, tibble(user_files,
    person_id = sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(user_files))))
```

Comment: This works, thanks so much! The only issue though is now the indexing of df$timestamp is off. If I would like to reference df$timestamp[i] within the for loop and have it match the timestamp for the same person_id as the name of the csv file. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @DrWampa One option is `i1 <- match(df$person_id, v1)]` and then `i2 <- !is.na(i1)`, then you loop it like `tmp <- df$timestamp[i1[i2]]` and user_files2 <- user_files[i1[i2]]` so that you will have corresponding 'tmp' and 'user_files2

Comment: @DrWampa I see 8 observations in both

Comment: thank you. However, it's still off. The result when I run that looks like this:

```
> user_files2
[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6
```
and

```
> tmp
[1] "02:26:10.000000" "02:26:10.000000" "03:45:37.000000" "22:03:39.000000" "11:46:24.000000" "18:26:55.000000"
[7] "18:26:55.000000" "17:01:20.000000"
```

df$person_id and df$timestamp don't match...

Comment: For example, the second tmp observation for person_id == 1 should be "03:45:37.000000" but it's just "02:26:10.000000" repeated

Comment: Can you show the `user_files` for testing.  I meant the the `user_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", path = here("data"),
                           full.names = TRUE)` and not the one after your subset.  I hope you didn't subset it with your next step

Comment: @DrWampa I think you can directly subset the `timestamp` i.e. `df$timestamp[i2]
[1] "02:26:10.000000" "03:45:37.000000" "22:03:39.000000" "11:46:24.000000" "23:16:05.000000"` The `match` `i1` was based on the match with 'id'

Comment: @DrWampa Try the update in my post.  It is better to have a single dataset instead of doing `match` and subsetting further

Comment: I agree - unfortunately the size of the datasets I'm working with (each csv file has hundreds of millions of rows) causes my computer to crash, so I have to go the long way around. Your suggestion of df$timestamp[i2] rather than df$timestamp[i1[i2]] worked - thanks so much!